# How to set a service port for ingresses in helmfile?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, helmfile

I'm new to Kubernetes and Helm and want to create a SSO with OIDC using [vouch-proxy](https://github.com/vouch/vouch-proxy)
I found a [tutorial](https://medium.com/@msvechla/attribute-based-access-control-with-oidc-and-nginx-ingress-controller-in-kubernetes-169481ff2f22) which explains how to do it and was able to write some [helmfiles](https://github.com/roboll/helmfile) that were accepted by kubernetes.

I added the ingress configuration to the `values.yaml` that I load in my `helmfile.yaml`.

helmfile.yaml

```yaml
bases:
- environments.yaml

---

releases:
  - name: "vouch"
    chart: "halkeye/vouch"
    version: {{ .Environment.Values.version }}
    namespace: {{ .Environment.Values.namespace }}
    values:
    - values.yaml
```

values.yaml

```yaml
# vouch config
# bare minimum to get vouch running with OpenID Connect (such as okta)
config:
  vouch:
    some:
      other:
      values:
# important part
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hosts:
  - "vouch.minikube"
  paths:
    - /
```

With this configuration helmfile creates an Ingress for the correct host, but when I open the URL in my Browser it returns a `404 Not Found` which makes sense, since I didn't specify the correct port (9090).

I tried some notations to add the port but it lead to either helmfile not updating the pod or `500 Internal Server Errors`.

How can I add a port in the configuration? And is it the "correct" way to do it? Or should ingresses be handled by kubectl still?

Comment: If possible, please include the output of `helm template .`